# How to get row with largest value?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

What I thought would work is:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer_sale
WHERE sale_date < '2019-02-01'
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING sale_date = MAX(sale_date)
```

But running this results in an error

> HAVING clause expression references column `sale_date` which is
>   neither grouped nor aggregated

Is there another way to achieve this in Spanner? And more generally, why isn't the above allowed?

**Edit**

Example of data in `customer_sale` table:

```
customer_id         sale_date
-------------------------------
    1                  Jan 15
    1                  Jan 30
    1                  Feb 2
    1                  Feb 4
    2                  Jan 15
    2                  Feb 2
```

And the expected result:

```
customer_id         sale_date
-------------------------------
    1                  Jan 30
    2                  Jan 15
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add the schema of your table and an example

Comment: `customer_id LONG, sale_date TIMESTAMP`. The example is the query above, though maybe something could be more clear?

Comment: I do not understand HAVING sale_date = MAX(sale_date), if sale date is a timestamp,  what should MAX of a timestamp return ? You want the row with the largest value of what ?

Comment: By example, I meant to show me 3-4  rows in that table and what should be the output of your query.

Comment: Edited with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A HAVING clause in SQL specifies that an SQL SELECT statement should
>   only return rows where aggregate values meet the specified conditions.
>   It was added to the SQL language because the WHERE keyword could not
>   be used with [aggregate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function)

This is the test table I am using:

```
index, customer_id, sale_date 

1   1   2017-08-25T07:00:00Z 

2   1   2017-08-26T07:00:00Z 

3   1   2017-08-27T07:00:00Z 

4   1   2017-08-28T07:00:00Z 

5   2   2017-08-29T07:00:00Z 

6   2   2017-08-30T07:00:00Z
```

With this query:

```
 Select customer_id, max(sale_date) as max_date
 from my_test_table
 group by customer_id;
```

I get this result:

```
 customer_id    max_date

 1              2017-08-28T07:00:00Z

 2              2017-08-30T07:00:00Z
```

Also including where statement:

```
 Select customer_id, max(sale_date) as max_date
 from my_test
 where sale_date < '2017-08-28'
 group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work - note this question is specifically GCP Cloud Spanner, not standard SQL

Comment: Again - this isn't a SQL question :P

Comment: I did this in Spanner.

Comment: Ah hah, I see - apologies! I assumed it was just normal SQL in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this way I was able to solve. If you have a quite big table it might take some time.

Basically, joining your normal table with the table which has records with maximum values solves it.

```
select c.* from 
(select * from customer_sale WHERE sale_date < '2019-02-01') c
inner join 
(SELECT customer_id, max(sale_date) as max_sale_date FROM customer_sale WHERE 
sale_date < '2019-02-01' group by customer_id) max_c
on c.customer_id = max_c.customer_id and c.sale_date = max_c.sale_date
```